# font-awesome not loaded in https gives error in web browser console but not give error in http ? how to fix

Tags: css, codeigniter, https, font-awesome, mixed-content

When I change my website URL HTTP to https, we change in source code HTTP to https still we faced mixed content error in chrome console. this line is written in the console:-Mixed Content: The page at 
`https://example.com/` was loaded over HTTPS but requested an insecure font `http://www.example.com/resource/home/new_resources/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0`. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
My website is use Codeigniter framework,Apache 2.3,mysql
[image]

Comment: please suggest your view

Comment: post your .htaccess and base_url and url you searched

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin .htaccess file

Comment: .hta file is too long but i used latest html 5 bottle

Comment: Used below code in .htaccess

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(woff)$">
    Header unset Vary
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(eot)$">
    Header unset Vary
</FilesMatch>


$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.mywebsites.com';

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to yours `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

then change your `base_url` like this `https://www.yoursite.com`

Comment: thanks for reply what i have to write in REQUEST_URI can i check this code in local ?

Comment: Yes you can check it.

Comment: You can use request_uri like this [link](https://gist.github.com/pwenzel/4567675)

Comment: these line are not working, give error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: So. Dont use request_uri only write your main url